Bayesian models comparison
I have two sets of paired samples, each consisting of 3,000 data points. Each value in these samples represents the output of a specific model.

The first model, which serves as the validation reference, is based on field measurements with known predictors and an error margin of 10-20% due to its theoretical assumptions.

The second model is based on estimated measurements with an error margin of 10%, but the predictors are unknown.


Additionally, both samples are not normally distributed.
I'm looking to evaluate the prediction performance of the second model using a Bayesian approach, without considering the contributions of the predictors.
Could anyone recommend references for tackling this problem with Bayesian methods? Examples in R would be very helpful.
Thank you!
